# Disable VSCode keybindings when switching keyboards

Tags: visual-studio-code, key-bindings, input-method

I have a lot of custom keybindings when attaching my non-English Windows-Keyboard to my English Mac.

When working directly with the Mac, I have to disable some of the bindings by commenting out a big section in the keybindings.json.

How can I automate this settings switch?

I know that keybindings use a `when` clause, but I did not find a way to check which keyboard is active or if I am on battery or not, or any other difference in the two setups.

Comment: for the computer all keyboards are the same, the OS translates the keycodes to keys based on the selected language, the actual print on the keys is just decoration for the user

Answer (score 0):

You can use the extension [Extra Context](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rioj7.extra-context).

You can set (or toggle) a context variable to select a bunch of keybindings.

You can use [multi-command](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ryuta46.multi-command) to combine several set-on set-off for variables to select a particular keyboard.